# Why are emojis replacing website icons in safari?

Tags: bug, mobile-safari, emoji

I have a iPhone 8 and I noticed a few months ago that when I go on certain websites such as ESPN, specific symbols such as the recruit rating stars has been replaced by random Emojis. I’m not sure why this is and I haven’t heard of it happening to anyone else.

[image: Example of emojis replacing web symbols/icons]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you share the link to the webpage from the screenshot.

Comment: Here is the link to the website: https://247sports.com/college/north-carolina/Season/2021-Football/Commits/

Comment: Did you try to reset Safari caches et al via Settings?

Comment: I did and nothing changed, I even have content blockers and the web inspector enabled.

Comment: Actually, I kind of like it better this way, but I suppose that's not the point... Is it the same emojis every time, or do the emojis change when you reload the page, or shift to different pages?

Comment: It’s the same emojis every time.